# How can I get info from Google Analytics from a Laravel app?

Tags: laravel-5, google-analytics-api

Each user will have different data/stats from Google Analytics.
I am not sure what info to ask/save on each user profile.

I need to display stats like top referrers, total visitors, etc.
I would like an example for this using google/apiclient

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can use the google core reporting and google core management APIs. See below for documentation.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/